# List all key ids in the AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there a way in the AWS to list all AWS keys (ids only of course) of all users in the account?

I'm trying to track down some keys that I don't know who/what they belong to.

Comment: You can do it easily via CLI: https://gist.github.com/mafonso/7ee51981581f544ed52c. Contrary to the comment there, I don't see the actual keys in the "Credential report" CSV generated by the console.

Comment: If you know what account it is used, I think you can search within the IAM console for Key ID. Just paste it into the search box.